# keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey: does it trigger changes recursively?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I'm reading the Key-Value Observing guide from Apple, and it hasn't explained one point in detail.

My question is: say I have a `name` property that's dependent on `firstName` and `lastName`, and I also have another property `group` that's dependent on `name` and `gender`.

Following the guide, I've written this

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingName {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"lastName",@"firstName",nil];
}
```

When writing the corresponding method for `group`, can I write it like this

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingGroup {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"name",@"gender",nil];
}
```

Or I have to add all the related properties

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingGroup {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"firstName",@"lastName",@"gender",nil];
}
```

Note that both `group` and `name` are computed, readonly properties.

Comment: You probably meant `keyPathsForValuesAffectingGroup` in case 2 and 3. - I strongly assume that the "recursive" method 2 works, did you try it?

Comment: @MartinR corrected. I haven't tested it but I think method 2 should work. What I'm mostly uncertain about is if method 1 would work - if it works than I can save a lot of typing

Comment: It seems that I expressed myself badly. With "method 2" I meant your second code block in the question (using `[NSSet setWithObjects:@"name",@"gender",nil]`). I assume that will work.

Comment: @MartinR OK I will try it when I have time. My main confusion is that it seems to me that a notification will only be sent when a setter is invoked; in this case `name` cannot be set and thus I'm afraid the notification would never be sent even if the computed value of `name` changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people here have got the right idea but to confirm this I've set up a test project with exactly the same code mentioned in my question.

And the result: it works for both ways.

Comment: Yes, but this tests for a concrete case on a concrete implementation of cocoa on a concrete implementation of Mac OS or iOS. Personally I would rely on it, too. +1

Answer (score 2):

If your questions means ...

> Can `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<key>` be chained to indirectly affect keys through several dependant properties?

... then the answer is yes.

Edit: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey%3a) on `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` confirms support for indirect dependent notifications.

Your last comment seems to suggest that you expect KVO notifications (indirect or not) being sent when directly changing an ivar. That's not the case. KVO relies on using the proper setter or on manually announce the change by sending `will/didChangeValueForKey:`

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand, so my two methods listed above for `..AffectingGroup` will both work right?

Comment: @Nikolai But what makes you sure, that the first affected property will send the announcement methods?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you mean, why KVO notifications are sent *at all* or why the chained properties are notified from the original mutation?

Comment: The second alternative: It is possible to write code, that 1. informs the observers for the changed key, 2. informs the observers for the affected key (1st level of dependency), but without 3. triggering a search on the affected keys of the affected key again (2nd level of dependency). I do not believe that, but it is possible

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad If I get you right you are speculating about Apple's possible implementation of KVO. To me it seems irrelevant whether or not one can write code that does this or that. What's important is what Apple says about what its implementation does. The documentation of `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` seems to confirm that it supports three-way indirect notifications: It explains the dependent notifications by internally registering for the dependent keys which, in turn, means recursive notifications would work. My own testing confirms this (at least from OS X 10.5 and iOS 2.0).

Comment: The documentation does not "seem to confirm", that it is chained up. "When an observer for the key is registered with an instance of the receiving class, key-value observing itself automatically observes all of the key paths for the same instance, and *sends change notifications for the key to the observer* when the value for any of those key paths changes." There is simply nothing that depending keys of depending keys are searched. It is only about observers of the depending key. In my comment I simply said, that implementations are possible to negotiate the Q. What makes you sure?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad To me the quoted documentation sounds like the implementation recursively registers (internal) observers for dependent keys and notifies them. This means that a chain of dependent observations would notify the original observer in the end. But you are of course right that the documentation says nothing explicitly about how all this works.

Comment: That is, what I wanted to say: This would be a good implementation, but other implementations are possible. Personally I would rely on it, but it is not documented. Somebody should file a doc bug. You or me? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that this will work, because it would be hard to let it not work.

Let us imagine, that you have three external (= different objects) observers for the properties.

What happens:

A. The opening door for KVO is a message didChangeValueForKey: to the observed object. If you have turned on automatic KVO, this message is sent automatically, when the setter for the key is called. (This is done in a dynamic generated subclass, which overwrites the setter.)

B. Then KVO code is triggered that looks semantically like this: (And it is simplified for only supporting keys, but not key paths.)

```
NSSet *observers = kvoBucket[key];
for( id observer in observers )
{
    [observer observeValue:[self valueForKey:key] forKeyPath:key …]
}
```

C. With affecting keys there has to be a second loop, informing about a change of the depending properties. (I assume, that this list is generated at the initialization of the class' object or adding the observation.)

```
// Inform observers
NSSet *observers = kvoBucket[key];
for( id observer in observers )
{
    [observer observeValue:[self valueForKey:key] forKeyPath:key …]
}

// Scan for affected properties
NSSet *keyOfaffectedProperties = affectedPropertiesBucket[key];
for( NSString *key in keyOfaffectedProperties )
{
    // trigger kvo for affected property
}
```

No let us sit down on the developer's chair. He can duplicate the first loop into the second loop. In this case it would not work. But this is duplicate code. (And the real code is more complicated for sure.) Why should he do that? Everyone of us would say: I already have this code! Let's use it again:

```
- (void)informOberserversForChangeOfKey:(NSString*)key
// Inform observers
NSSet *observers = kvoBucket[key];
for( id observer in observers )
{
    [observer observeValue:[self valueForKey:key] forKeyPath:key …]
}

// Scan for affected properties
NSSet *keyOfaffectedProperties = affectedPropertiesBucket[key];
for( NSString *keyOfAffectedProperty in keyOfaffectedProperties )
{
    [self informObserversForChangeOfKey:keyOfAffectedProperty];
}
```

If there is no optimization, which makes recursion impossible or inconvenient, it should work. I would bet it works – But only a small amount of money. ;-)